# How to add/insert/upload videos in Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla, upload

I am using Joomla 3.x in a project. I am not able to find a help on how to add/upload/insert videos in Joomla 3.x. While I googled, so many videos/pages helped me to insert/upload/embed Videos from the Youtube Channels, but how to add videos from my laptop/computers. Can any one provide a step-by-step guide to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a video to your website using FTP or similar and then use a free or paid third party extension e.g. [AllVideos](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/allvideos/) to display the video. See [the AllVideos documentation](http://www.joomlaworks.net/support/docs/allvideos) for details. If hosting the video locally on the website, you might also need to upload a suitable preview image.

You might also be able to [use HTML5 to display the video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) using the following code or similar:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Depending on where your website is hosted, it may be better from a performance and bandwidth point of view to upload the video to YouTube or similar and use a free or paid third party extension e.g. AllVideos to display the video.